# ESP8266 constantly reconnects

Tags: esp8266

So, my ESP8266 now has this problem where every three seconds it goes offline for a split second and the light blinks as it comes back. It seems to be constantly resetting... I recieved this problem when I had it connected to a power brick in my pocket, and I am pretty sure it happened because of static. I would have bought a protective case for it but it appears that I csn only find 3D printed parts but I currently do not own a 3D printer. I am wondering how I can fix it. If I try to re-flash it the re-flash fails because it disconnects before the flashing finishes.

Comment: It may be your code getting into a loop that takes longer than the watchdog timeout.

Comment: If it is static damage its unlikely you can fix it.  Have you tried running it of a different power supply?

Comment: @CodeGorilla I managed to fix the problem, I just needed to re-flash with a python script rather than Ubuntu's ESPTool.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix the problem. I have a PC with Ubuntu 16.04 and I tried to re-flash it using Ubuntu's ESPTool, which was why it was failing. I noticed it failed constantly at a certain point. To fix it, I re-flahed the firmware with [this](https://github.com/themadinventor/esptool.git) python script, and it was successful.